# Why do eps images overlap the captions in subfigures?

Tags: floats, xetex, subfloats, eps, subcaption

I'm using the package subcaption within an scrreprt compiling with XeTeX/XeLaTeX. When using subfigures for 4 images in a grid view, the images are not centered and overlap the middle subcaptions. It seems like this is just happening for my .eps-figures.

Please see a MWE and a picture of my problem below.

What is happening here? What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass[
pagesize=automedia,
headsepline=true,
mpinclude=false,
parskip=half,
DIV=12,
BCOR=12mm,
ngerman
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage[]{babel}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
%   
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Quadrat 1}\label{fig:Q1}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}        
    \caption{Quadrat 2}\label{fig:Q2}
\end{subfigure} 

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Quadrat 3}\label{fig:Q3}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.49\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Quadrat 4}\label{fig:Q4}
\end{subfigure}         
%
\caption{4 Quadrate}\label{fig:Qs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The Problem also appears, if I use `\par` instead of the blank line between subfigure 2 and 3. With `\par\medskip` or `\par\bigskip` I can correct the vertical distance but not the ill centered pictures.

[image]

---

Find the eps here: [EPS Upload](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/520136/Beispiel.eps)

Comment: Without the figure how should we know. There is no problem if one use demo figures, i.e. `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}`. Have you tried adding `\fbox{...}` around each included figure to see if it behaves? Some EPS files have bad bounding boxes.

Comment: My knowledge about eps is too small. Didn't know about those bounding boxes. The used eps is uploaded to the post. `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` crashes my XeTeX so I don't use these. PNGs or `\rule{\linewidth}{100pt}` works for me, so I thought it is an EPS problem. `\fbox{...}` changes the positioning but doesn't fix it. The black borders are not superimposed to my figure. The boxes are positioned perfectly...

Comment: Place `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` before `xltxtra` then it does not crash. The point of the `\fbox` is to see if the generated box matched the expected size of the EPS. It should create a small border around the image. If the EPS extends this extra border, then the EPS might not be as good as it should be

Comment: I do not get any overlap as shown in your image above. Using TUG TeX Live 2012 frozen.

Comment: That's strange. I'm using MiKTeX 2.9.4533 with TeXnicCenter on XP. XeLaTeX => PDF. `xltxtra` 2010-09-21; `caption` 2013-05-21.

Comment: My caption version is slightly older as TL froze before the new version arrived. (Note that the editor is not relevant). Could you post your result of compiling our MWE?

Comment: What do you refer to with "our MWE"? If you mean the effect of your hints for so far, it looks like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/520136/fbox.jpg).

Comment: I just noticed, that cropping the images with `trim` and `clip` results in strange things (crops on top instead of bottom or crops two sides instead of one). I don't know, how to continue. BoundaryBoxes are set and I cleaned the eps with GhostView. `%%BoundingBox: 71 17 722 596`. I tested several things such as `trim`, `clip`, `bb`and `eps2pdf` without results.

Comment: Dids you notice how the boxes around the EPS does not match the boxes inside the EPS. This is indicating that the bounding box is wrong.

Comment: The EPS have some binary junk added to it (before `%%PS`), have you tried `epstool --copy Beispiel.eps Beispiel1.eps`. Then my `gv` reacts much better to it.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. The junk is already removed by this explanation: http://www.rz.uni-kiel.de/ausgabe/bbox/ (with ghostview which should be the same as epstool.). My new file is uploadet to the post. The bounding Box is not set to `0 0 urc urc`; Is that a problem?

Comment: It should not be a problem. Interestingly I do not see any difference before and after `epstool`. It might be an idea to open a new question discussing the bounding box when using `xelatex`

Comment: Maybe related: the thread ["eps inclusion by dvipdfmx and xdvipdfmx"](http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2013-May/033670.html) in the mailing list for TeX Live last month.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek sounds like it.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: sounds pretty much alike, but the recommended changes of the mailing list post are already implemented in my local version of `xetex-def` and `dvipdfmx-def`. No `hoffset` or `voffset` included here. Both files are equal to the CTAN-versions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2013 the configuration of in file `dvipdfmx.cfg` (also used for XeTeX's `xdvipdfmx`) was changed to add `-dEPSCrop` for the conversion of EPS to PDF.
After that TeX reads the PostScript BoundingBox, but the driver embeds the PDF with a different BoundingBox virtually starting at (0,0).

Also `xetex.def` (and `dvipdfmx.def` etc.) were changed to handle the new settings.
But if the changes are out of sync, the problems remain.

As you have the new `xetex.def`, I would check `dvipdfmx.cfg`, if `-dEPSCrop` is present in the conversion of PostScript files, e.g. (TeX Live):

```
D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"
```

If your version (`miktex/dvipdfm/config/dvipdfmx.cfg`) contains `-sPAPERSIZE=a0` instead, then try to replace it with `-dEPSCrop`.

Comment: That works perfect for the MWE shown above. Will this file stay like it is now? Will `dvipdfmx.cfg` be replaced  someday by MikTeX? Unluckily cropping the images still doesn't work. I tried `trim= 0 100 0 0,clip,...` and also with `cm` or `mm` but it crops the top. Seems like it is trimming like `trim=r t r t`. E. g. `trim= 0 100 0 100` trims 200 (or something alike) from the top. Shall I open a new post for that?

Comment: @LaRiFaRi: MiKTeX is maintained, there is a mailing list, make a bug report or ask the maintainer. `trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>`. If, after resolving the issue of this question, your `trim` behaves differently, then make a new question with complete example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Find here the [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2270/) on MiKTeX at SourceForge and the [new post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119732/how-is-cropping-for-eps-files-done-in-xelatex) to the cropping topic on TEX.SX

Answer (score -3):

Try running `latex`+`dvipdfm`+`viewpdf` rather than  `latex`+`dvi2ps`+`ps2pdf`+`viewpdf`. It worked for me.

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment.