# How is cropping for EPS-files done in XeLaTeX?

Tags: graphics, floats, xetex, eps, crop

When trying to crop an [EPS-figure](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/520136/Beispiel.eps) with `trim=<left> <bottom> <right> <top>, clip, ...` it results in strange behavior. Please find a MWE and a image of the result below.

It seems like the cropping is done only for the top and the right (or twice). In [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119154/why-do-eps-images-overlap-the-captions-in-subfigures) you can read the proceeding until now, to get the boundaries of the EPS recognized by `xetex.def` and `dvipdfmx.def`.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{No clipping}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[trim = 100 0 0 0, clip, width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Trimming left}
\end{subfigure} 

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0 100 0 0, clip, width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Trimming bottom}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0 0 100 0, clip, width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Trimming right}
\end{subfigure} 

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[trim = 0 0 0 100, clip, width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Trimming top}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[trim = 100 100 100 100, clip, width=\linewidth]{Beispiel.eps}
    \caption{Cropping all}
\end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`trim` for EPS files with `xetex.def` is broken. As workaround convert the EPS files to PDF:

- `epstopdf file.eps`
- `ps2pdf -dEPSCrop file.eps`

Then include the PDF version of the images in the TeX file.

Comment: Ok, taking a pdf works. Transferring with `\usepackage{epstopdf}`, `\includegraphics{Beispiel}` and `initexmf --edit-config-file=miktex\config\pdftex.ini` => `EnableWrite18=t` results in `xelatex> Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than 'pdftex.def' are not supported.`. PDF made by ghostview has a lot of margin. Inkscape works perfect. But not a solution for all my figures to transfer them to PDF by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Clipping is broken in `xetex.def` up to version 0.94, but this is fixed in version 0.95 and following. In the forthcoming TeX Live 2013 the version of `xetex.def` is 0.97. The most recent version corrects also some glitches in the order the options are processed.

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[clip,trim=3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm,width=.5\textwidth]{tiger.eps}

\newpage

\includegraphics[trim=3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm,width=.5\textwidth]{tiger.eps}
\end{document}
```

### TeX Live 2013

[image]

### TeX Live 2012

[image]

Comment: How did you get  TeX Live 2013?

Comment: He's testing TL 2013 (http://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html)

Comment: @mozartstraße Test version, but now it's the one that will be released. Just a few days left. Don't run to the servers that provide the test version: they are few and overloading them is not a good idea. Just be patient for a couple of weeks.

Comment: `trim=3cm 3cm 3cm 3cm` should have select the middle of the image, not the lower left part. Thus `xetex.def` 0.97/TL 2013 is still broken. :-(

Comment: Exactly. I'm using Version 0.96 and it doesn't work. Or are you, @egreg, referring to the order of `clip` and `trim`? I will try the different orders. (Edit: order does no effect...)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Uh! The upgrade broke a fix?

Comment: Ok, just found out, I'm also using .97 containing the wrong line `\ProvidesFile{xetex.def} [2013/04/29 v0.96 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)]`. Is there a possibility to obtain .95 anywhere? Where can I report a bug? Can't find contact to the maintainers.