# Figures misplaced in recent version of MiKTeX

Tags: floats, positioning, miktex, dvipdfmx

After a MiKTeX update, eps graphs were misplaced and appeared overlap with captions and text in pdf files.  They worked perfect in earlier MiKTeX 2.9.  Figures in dvi files worked fine as desired.

System is Windows 7, tex files are edited and processed in Texmaker.

Exactly the same question was posted earlier by someone else, but somehow removed without being answered.

In an active post [Why do eps images overlap the captions in subfigures?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119154/why-do-eps-images-overlap-the-captions-in-subfigures) this problem was addressed in the [answer of Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119697/).  My question: Is there solutions other than what is described below?  If the following is the only or good solution, could anyone tell me what other files to modify so that they are consistent with the change in `dvipdfmx.cfg`?  For example, what are "the conversion of PostScript files, e.g. (TeX Live)" and where are they located?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you. And a suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: Instead of copying and breaking the formatting you should have linked to the question and answer, as I did it for you.

Comment: The example in the question you linked too works fine for me in a current miktex, and dvipdfmx.cfg contains the changes suggested bei Heiko. In case you are not using xelatex but latex + dvipdfmx: make sure that you are using the correct driver option when loading graphicx: `\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}`. If the problem persist: make a complete, minimal example and put the image somewhere for download.